# Непонятные ARP-запросы

Tags: сеть, wifi, arp

Сижу уже давно с вай фай роутера. И постоянно какие-то перебои со связью.

Захожу в `Wireshark` и смотрю что да как. И вижу `АRP`-запрос от моего компа(мол кто такой 192.168.1.3) в сети 6-8 устройств. Потом смотрю и столько этих запросов сыпется.

Где-то штук 30 в минуту, и на все роутер старается ответить.Но это еще не всё! Вся абсурдность что после ответа комп дальше кидает те же самые ARP-запросы и роутер опять на них отвечает.
К тому же мне даже кажется что ARP-запросы сформированы не правильно. В них указан айпи адрес+Мак, которые роутер спрашивает.

[image: 1 из ARP-пакетов]

Comment: А в чем проблема? Тридцать запросов в минуту - это вообще ни о чем, а не нагрузка.

Comment: Почему он просто не закеширует айпи и всё?Дело еще в том что сеть из-за этого мусора грузиться, а она и так слабая

Comment: Там передается килобайт пять в минуту, ну какая нагрузка.

Comment: Но это ведь не должно так быть. Мало ли, может малварь пытается вылезти или что. Вот и хотел понять

Comment: Оба MAC присутствуют, так как это не поиск хоста, а обновление arp-таблицы при известном хосте. почему так много не понятно, согласен, что такого быть не должно. Ощущение, что таймаут для обновления записей arp-таблицы 2 секунды (раз 30 в минуту), что нестандартно для windows. Такое может наблюдаться при потерях ответных пакетов, чего быть не может, если wireshark у вас на 1.3 запущен (он же их увидел)

Comment: Mike, а есть ли способ этот тайм аут поменять?